# SaltStack: Reason why postgres_user.absent fails?

Tags: saltstack

The Salt state [postgres_user.absent](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.postgres_user.html#salt.states.postgres_user.absent) fails:

```
      ID: remove_foobar_vums_dci__database_user
Function: postgres_user.absent
    Name: foobar_vums_dci
  Result: False
 Comment: User foobar_vums_dci failed to be removed
 Started: 10:14:07.614833
Duration: 9523.131 ms
 Changes:
```

Why does it fail?

I could start some guessing now. But in this particular moment, I am not in the mood for guessing.

Is there a way to tickle saltstack a bit to tell me the reason for this failure?

## Update

Several months later we came across a similar error in `postres_database.absent`.

This time we found the corresponding issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/42833

Comment: maybe permission issue?

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL thank you for guessing. My goal is to get a meaningful error message. The particular failure is not that important for me right now.

Comment: Did you try debug logging?

Comment: @Schrute unfortunately this was not reproducible.

Comment: @guettli please don't edit the solution into the question, post it as an answer instead and accept it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider there is no solution. Just a hint to the root of the issue.

Comment: Nevertheless it's an answer.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you are right.